# Understanding functions (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

I see the below function used in a bash script:

```
LOG_FILE="/root/collect.log";\
date_info() {
        local cmd; cmd=$(basename $0)
        echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) $cmd.info: $*" >>"$LOG_FILE"
        >&2 echo "$cmd.info: $*"
}
```

Can someone help me understand this function, please? I know that everything is being collected in the log_file, which is in path `/root/collect.log`, but I cannot understand its details apart from the date and time.

Regards,
Tayto

Comment: It only defines a variable and a function. But does nothing of interest. It also has some bad practice, but I won't go into that.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I have just added here a part of the code and requested the detail of the function. Rest I have not added. As a function, of course, it doesn`t do much. :)

Comment: So is it a question about "understanding functions", or is it about understanding this function?

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially just a logging function.

```
local cmd; cmd=$(basename $0)
```

here `cmd` is being declared as a local variable which means it will only be available inside this function.  Then it is being assigned the value of `$(basename $0)` which will expand to the name of the shell or shell script.

```
echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) $cmd.info: $*" >>"$LOG_FILE"
```

Here you echo the date in [rfc-3339 format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) (note this is likely only an available option with GNU date so this command would probably not be very portable), the value of `cmd` appended by `.info:` so if your running this from `script.sh` it will be `script.sh.info:`, and then [`$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) represents all arguments given to the function expanded by the first character in `IFS`.

So if you were to run `date_info unable to do the thing` in your `script.sh` you would get a line in your log file like this:

```
2022-04-20 06:35:00-06:00 script.sh.info: unable to do the thing
```

finally the line:

```
>&2 echo "$cmd.info: $*"
```

This line redirects stdout to stderr and then echos basically the same thing minus the date to your terminal.

---

Additionally the `;\` at the end of `LOG_FILE="/root/collect.log";\` is sort of nonsensical.  `;` is a command separator which in a shell script is unnecessary at the end of a newline and then the `\` is escaping the following newline...they sort of cancel each other out and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score -1):

### TL;DR

It's a logging function (possibly attempting to create syslog-like entries) that looks like it was built with a lot of cut-and-paste. A deeper analysis and a refactoring are provided below.

### What the Originally-Posted Code is Doing

---

*NB: The original code relies on GNU date (BSD date will not work), and quite likely Bash although there are no specific Bashisms according to the [checkbashisms](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devscripts/tree/scripts/checkbashisms.pl) utility.*

---

The following is a Bourne-based script written by someone who did a lot of copy-and-paste from other sources. It seems intended to appends a log message of severity "info" to a log file, and a copy of the message to standard error. It's poorly written (defined as "it makes shellcheck complain"), and could be improved in a number of ways. The original code as posted is:

```bsh
LOG_FILE="/root/collect.log";\
date_info() {
        local cmd; cmd=$(basename "$0)
        echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) $cmd.info: $*" >>"$LOG_FILE"
        >&2 echo "$cmd.info: $*"
}
```

Since variables in all-caps are generally meant to be exported environment variables, and you don't seem to be deliberately avoiding bashisms, the code  could be rewritten with a more standard logging format, some built-in Bash expansions, and generally clearer semantic intent using any recent version of Bash and GNU versions of the `date` and `tr` utilities, e.g. `gdate` and `gtr` on Darwin systems with GNU utilities installed.

### The Original Code, Refactored

Based on a number of assumptions about the code and its intent—you will have to validate some of these things as they can't be gleaned just from looking at the original source—this is what I would consider a more flexible and readable refactoring, although you may need to tweak the format and severity levels for your specific use case.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set a default logfile if one isn't already
# present in the environment.
: "${LOG_FILE:=/root/collect.log}"
export LOG_FILE

# Set the default log level to INFO if the
# environment variable isn't already set.
: "${DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL:=INFO}"
export DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL

# Log a message to a file and to standared error.
#
# NB: You may want to change the possible values
# for log levels (a.k.a. severity) based on your
# target logging system. For example, syslog
# also accepts `CRIT`, `ALERT`, and `EMERG`.
log_message () {
    local date filename log_level log_msg
    
    filename=$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ".sh")
    date=$(date --rfc-3339=seconds | tr -d '\r\n')
    log_level="${1:-$DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL}"
    log_level="${log_level^^}"

    # Remove the first positional parameter if it's a
    # defined log severity level.
    [[ "${1@U}" =~ DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL ]] && shift

    log_msg="[${date}] $log_level -- ${filename}: $*"
    echo "$log_msg" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "$log_msg"  > /dev/stderr
}
```

---

*NB: The refactored script above doesn't report any Bashisms, although it clearly uses them. However, it runs clean with shellcheck. If portability trumps convenience, you can rewrite this to use standard *nix utilities rather than Bash expansions or other shell-specific features, but shell portability is out of scope for both the original question and this answer.*

---

Within the program, you can call the `log_message` function with or without a non-default severity level. For example, if the code was in *example_app.sh* then calling:

```bsh
log_message WARN "This is just an example."
```

within the script would log:

> ```
> [2022-04-20 11:10:01-04:00] WARN -- example_app: This is just an example.
> ```

to both *collect.log* and standard error.

### See Also

- [Syslog Severity Levels](https:////en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level)
- Ruby's [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class, format, and severity levels
- Bash's [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)
- Shellcheck [website](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and [source code](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck)